# Replace empty cells with logical 0's before cell2mat in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array, is-empty

I have an array of empty cells and ones that I want to convert to a logical array, where the empty cells are zeros. When I use cell2mat, the empty cells are ignored, and I end up with a matrix of solely 1's, with no reference to the previous index they held. Is there a way to perform this operation without using loops?

Example code:

```
for n=1:5              %generate sample cell array
    mycellarray{n}=1;
end
mycellarray{2}=[]      %remove one value for testing
```

Things I've tried:

```
mylogicalarray=logical(cell2mat(mycellarray));
```

which results in [1,1,1,1], not [1,0,1,1,1].

```
for n=1:length(mycellarray)
    if isempty(mycellarray{n})
       mycellarray{n}=0;
    end
end
mylogicalarray=logical(cell2mat(mycellarray));
```

which works, but uses loops.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you know your cell array is *only* going to contain ones and `[]` (which represent your zeroes), you can just use the function [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to get a logical index of the empty cells, then negate the index vector:

```
mylogicalarray = ~cellfun(@isempty, mycellarray);
% Or the faster option (see comments)...
mylogicalarray = ~cellfun('isempty', mycellarray);
```

If your cells *could* still contain zero values (not just `[]`), you could replace the empty cells with 0 by first using the function [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to find an index for the empty cells:

```
emptyIndex = cellfun('isempty', mycellarray);     % Find indices of empty cells
mycellarray(emptyIndex) = {0};                    % Fill empty cells with 0
mylogicalarray = logical(cell2mat(mycellarray));  % Convert the cell array
```

Comment: Calling `cellfun('isempty',mycellarray)` is much faster than the function handle; `isempty()` is one of several functions enjoying massive speed increases when named explicitly in the `cellfun()` call.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `~` in front of `cellfun`?

Comment: Ah, `~` is the logical operator not.

Comment: timings on calling cellfun('isempty',mycellarray) vs cellfun(@isempty,mycellarray) for 367x367 sized cells (on a regular laptop):
'isempty': 0.002032
@isempty: 0.083621
Thx for the tip strange_dreams!

Answer (score 8):

```
mycellarray( cellfun(@isempty, mycellarray) ) = {0};
mylogicalarray = logical(cell2mat(mycellarray));
```

Comment: This answer helped me.